# Matar un hilo en Android onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, hilos

Estoy tratando de matar este hilo en cuanto pulse el boton de retroceso. Pero en **"HiloConsumo"** no recoge bien la referencia del hilo

```
        new Thread("HiloConsumo") {
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------");
                    // stock.print();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (HiloConsumo != null)//valida si existe.
    {
        HiloConsumo.interrupt();  //Interrumpe su ejecución.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería la forma correcta de interrumpir la ejecución de un [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()):

Creas el Thread:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread("ThreadEduardo");
```

de esta forma validas si existe y procedes a detener su ejecución.

```
  if(myThread != null){  //valida si existe.
      myThread.interrupt();  //Interrumpe su ejecución.          
  }
```

El método [stop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) no es usado ya que es obsoleto.

> **stop()** Este método fue obsoleto en API nivel 1. Este método es inherentemente inseguro. Detener un subproceso con Thread.stop hace
>   que desbloquee todos los monitores que ha bloqueado (como una
>   consecuencia natural de la excepción ThreadDeath no verificada que se
>   propaga en la pila).

---

Este es un ejemplo para que veas el funcionamiento del Thread y su interrupción.

Declaras una variable tipo `Thread`:

```
private Thread HiloConsumo;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
```

Crea una clase que extienda de Thread:

```
 private class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(true) {
                Log.d(TAG, "En ejecucion: " + HiloConsumo.getName() + " | " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                try {
                    sleep(1000); //pausa un segundo.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Crearias de esta forma tu Thread:

```
  HiloConsumo = new MyThread(); //crea instancia.
  HiloConsumo.setName("Hilo Eduardo"); //Asigna nombre.
  HiloConsumo.start(); //inicia Thread.
```

al llamar onBackPressed() podras ver que se interrumpe la ejecución:

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
        if (HiloConsumo != null)//valida si existe instancia de Thread.
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "interrumpe Thread!" + HiloConsumo.getName());
            HiloConsumo.interrupt();  //Interrumpe su ejecución.
        }
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que no tiene nombrado el Thread porque está usando el constructor por defecto y necesita usar el que recibe el nombre por parametro, pido permiso para agregar tu manera de matar el thread a mi respuesta

Comment: me pasa lo siguiente .... http://subefotos.com/ver/?d00547117f6010b2b51a6bcfd478725fo.jpg

Comment: @EduardoMéndez no se ve la imagen, agregala a tu pregunta o abre otra!

Comment: He puesto el nombre a pelo pero aun asi estoy haciendolo mal que podria ser? @Jorgesys

Comment: agrega una imagen o lo que te muestra en la consola. @EduardoMéndez

Comment: Me aparece **Cannot resolve symbol 'HiloConsumo'**

Comment: @EduardoMéndez me parece que estas confundiendo, lo que agregas como parametro es solo el nombre del Thread, HiloConsulo  es la instancia del Thread, voy a editar mi respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: Crea la referencia global `private Thread HiloConsumo;` despues asignalo cuando creas el `Thread`, `HiloConsumo = new Thread`...bla bla Y ya te funcionará. El error puede ser que lo estés declarando local o no lo estés declarando en ninguna parte. @EduardoMendez

Comment: @Jorgesys para que no se confunda, edita tu pregunta e inicia el hilo con .start() o adapta el código a su pregunta, no puede utilizar una referencia local si esta matando el hilo en otro método ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°

Comment: @EduardoMéndez he agregado un ejemplo para que haga fit con tu pregunta. Te sugiero revises en el LogCat los mensajes para mejor entendimiento.

Comment: gracias de verdad ;D funciono a la pefección !!